# RegEx for capturing and replacing digits in a pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I would like to replace the 3rd argument in the string with a new number (let's say 100).  The matched string always starts with `function`, with the first argument either `true` or `false`, and with the number as second argument.

```py
                                               Expected
                    |                             |
                    v                             v
'function(true, 0, 15)'   --> 'function(true, 0, 100)'  
'function(false, 0, 23)'  --> 'function(false, 0, 100)'
```

I have been reading the related posts but I believe I must have misunderstood some regex concept. The following code is that I had tried but it always replaces the whole string:

```py
import re
string = 'function(true, 0, 15)'
regex = re.compile('function\([a-zA-Z]*, [0-9]*, ([0-9]*)\)')
res = re.sub(regex, '100', string)

print(res) # 100
           # Expected: function(true, 0, 100)
```

**Question:** Could you point me out why the above code doesn't work? How would I write the code to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the number you are trying to replace is just followed by a closing parenthesis `)`, you can just use this `\d+(?=\s*\))` regex and replace it by `100` or whatever value you want. Try these Python codes,

```
import re
string = 'function(true, 0, 15)'
regex = re.compile(r'\d+(?=\s*\))')
res = re.sub(regex, '100', string)

print(res)
```

Prints,

```
function(true, 0, 100)
```

Also, the reason why your code isn't working as expected and is replacing whole of your string with `100` because the way you've written your regex, it matches your whole input and `re.sub` function replaces what all matches with second argument and hence all your input gets replaced with `100`. But instead what you want is, to just replace the third argument with `100` hence the way you should write your regex, should only match the third argument value, like demonstrated in below regex demo,

**[Regex Demo matching only what you want to replace](https://regex101.com/r/hB5Bho/1/)**

And your current regex matches whole of your input as shown in below demo,

**[Regex Demo with your regex matching whole input](https://regex101.com/r/hB5Bho/2/)**

Also, in case you feel better and you want to match whole input and then selectively replace only third argument, you can use this regex to capture the function name and first two parameters in group1 like you wanted to capture in your original regex,

```
(function\([a-zA-Z]*, [0-9]*, )[0-9]*\)
```

and replace it with `\g<1>100)` where `\g<1>` references the value captured in group1 and further it is replaced with `100)`

**[Regex Demo with full match and selected replacement](https://regex101.com/r/hB5Bho/3/)**

Comment: I believe it captures the number that I want: I tried `re.findall(regex, 'function(true, 0, 15)')` and it correctly returns `['15']`. I must have misunderstood the `re.sub` function

Comment: @IgNite: Yes, your number is captured well in group1 but as you are replacing with literal value `100` hence all matched string gets replaced with literal value only. If you want to match whole input but replace with selected parts, you can use groups to capture the content you want to retain and use backreferencing during replacement. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB5Bho/3/) where I am capturing the part you want to retain in group1 and replacing with `\g<1>100)` so group1 content is retained and further `100)` is added after that.

Comment: Now I understand it! I misunderstood the semantic of the `re.sub` function.

Answer (score 1):

This expression also might work:

```
(?:\d+)(\))
```

which has a non-capturing group with our desired digits `(?:\d+)`, followed by a right boundary `(\))`, which we can replace it with our new number and `$1`.

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:\d+)(\))"

test_str = "function(true, 0, 15)"

subst = "100\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VojjrA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, you can print everything before the match and everything after the match, then print it out with the new result like so:

```
regex = re.compile( '(function\([a-zA-Z]*, [0-9]*, )([0-9]*)(\))' )
res = re.sub( regex, r'\1 100\3', string )
```

Basically, I placed parenthesis around the text before the expected match and after the expected match. Then I print it out as `\1` (first match) `100` (new text) `\3` (third match).

The reason why I propose this particular expression is in case OP specifically needs to only match strings that also contain the preceding "function(" section (or some other pattern). Plus, this is just an extension of OP's solution, so it may be more intuitive to OP.

Comment: Thanks, this is in fact similar to my modified answer after reading Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi's answer and yours.